# get user data info by class (php)

Tags: php

I want to get a row from db and show in my page. Following code doesn't work and my browser hangs. and i don't know how fix it. Please help me.

Class :

```
public function get_calculate($id)
{
    if ($id != 0) {
        $stmt_select_calculate = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT analix_calculate.title,analix_calculate.basis FROM analix_calculate where analix_calculate.id=:calculate_id AND analix_calculate.is_active=1;');
        $stmt_select_calculate->bindValue(':calculate_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    } else {
        $stmt_select_calculate = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT analix_calculate.title,analix_calculate.basis FROM analix_calculate where analix_calculate.is_active=1;');
    }
    return $stmt_select_calculate->execute();
}
```

index.php :

```
<?php
include("../db/Database.php");
$databse = new Database();
$menu = $databse->get_calculate(0);
while ($row_select_calculate = $menu) {
?>
    <li>
        <a href="#0">
        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $row_select_calculate['title']?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You should replace `while ($row_select_calculate = $menu) {` into `foreach ($menu as $row_select_calculate){`

Comment: ^ Correct. And because `$row_select_calculate = $menu` is __always__ true, your script hangs.

Comment: @executable Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @u_mulder How can i fix it

Comment: Can you print the content of `$menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `$stmt_select_calculate->execute();` [returns](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues) bool value. You cannot iterate over bool value, it's obvious. So, you should return statement object itself:

```
public function get_calculate($id)
{
    if ($id != 0) {
        $stmt_select_calculate = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT analix_calculate.title,analix_calculate.basis FROM analix_calculate where analix_calculate.id=:calculate_id AND analix_calculate.is_active=1;');
        $stmt_select_calculate->bindValue(':calculate_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    } else {
        $stmt_select_calculate = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT analix_calculate.title,analix_calculate.basis FROM analix_calculate where analix_calculate.is_active=1;');
    }
    $stmt_select_calculate->execute();
    return $stmt_select_calculate;
}
```

In `index.php` you should `fetch` data:

```
$menu_stmt = $databse->get_calculate(0);
while ($row = $menu_stmt->fetch()) {
?>
    <li>
        <a href="#0">
        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $row['title']?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php
}
```